# How to redirect some URLs to another local port with .htaccess?

Tags: htaccess, apache, mod-rewrite

I have the .htaccess file in the root public_html directory. It contains the following:

```
Options -Indexes
Redirect / /dali

RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^api/(.*[^/])/?$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}:5000/$1 [R=301,L]
```

I wished this to forward all requests from `http://192.168.1.144/api/something` to `http://192.168.1.144:5000/something`. And if I try this in the [sandbox](https://htaccess.madewithlove.be/) - it is working:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/YothN.png]

And if I try resulting URL - it should work:

[image]

However in reality - it does not:

[image]

So it looks like mod_rewrite don't handles its work as I expect.

What can I do to track this out?

Comment: Given the code as posted, you would expect `/api/something` to be redirected as required. However, the `Redirect / /dali` directive is _suspect_. This would ordinarily result in a redirect-loop for anything other than URLs of the form `/api/<anything>` - since `Redirect` is prefix-matching and so `/` matches _everything_. However, you've stated that `/` is successfully redirected to `/dali` and no loop. If this is the case then there would seem to be something else that prevents this? Is `/dali` alias'd to another part of the filesystem? Any other `.htaccess` files in subdirectories?

Comment: ...I'm wondering if whatever it is that prevents the redirect loop is also preventing the mod_rewrite redirect to function as intended? This is assuming the that `/` to `/dali` redirect is being performed by `.htaccess` and not _something else_ (eg. server config, application logic, etc.)?

Comment: "This would ordinarily result in a redirect-loop for anything other than URLs of the form `/api/<anything>`" - this is assuming that port 5000 references a different part of the filesystem, otherwise every URL would potentially trigger a redirect-loop. (?)

Answer (score 1):

> `Redirect / /dali`

Ordinarily, this directive would result in a redirect loop<sup>***1**</sup> for URLs other than `/api/<something>` (since the mod_rewrite directive that follows takes priority), which leads me to think you don't have `.htaccess` overrides enabled to begin with (ie. `.htaccess` is not enabled)?

<sup>(***1** Unless perhaps you have another `.htaccess` file in a subdirectory that somehow prevents this redirect-loop, or perhaps the `/dali` subdirectory is Alias'd to a different part of the filesystem so the parent `.htaccess` file is not reprocessed? Or *something else*?!)</sup>

To enable `.htaccess` overrides, you need to set the appropriate `AllowOverride` directive in your server config (for the required directory). For example:

```
<Directory /path/to/public_html>
AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```

The "sandbox" tool you link to would seem to be incorrectly handling that `Redirect` directive and its prefix-matching behaviour<sup>***2**</sup>. Also, it only makes a single pass through the code - it doesn't simulate the redirect, so "redirect-loops" are not detected.

<sup>(***2** The `Redirect` directive is prefix-matching. eg. `Redirect / /dali` matches any URL that simply *starts* `/` - which naturally matches *everything*. However the "mwl htaccess tester" appears to treat this `Redirect` directive as an exact match and only matches `/` exactly, ie. the document root - this is incorrect.)</sup>

Otherwise, the `RewriteRule` directive actually looks OK, except that it possibly matches too much, since it will also match `/api/s/o/m/e/t/h/i/n/g` - is that the intention?

Comment: `Redirect / /dali` worked. At least if I visited `http://192.168.1.144/` I was found my self on `...1.144/dali` page as was expected.
As you've suggested I changed `AllowOverride` for  `<Directory /var/www/>` to `All` but Apache turned not to work (500 Error) until I returned this setting to `None`.
Regarding the last point: if `IP/api/s/o/m/e/t/h/i/n/g` will redirect to `IP:5000/s/o/m/e/t/h/i/n/g` - it is fine. But for now I don't need anything but the first word.

Comment: "`Redirect / /dali` worked." - Ok, although that wouldn't seem to be possible given just the code as posted - there must be _something else_ (see my comments above)? "I changed `AllowOverride` for `<Directory /var/www/>`" - that alone shouldn't result in a 500 error?! Check the server error log for details. Although, shouldn't you be targeting the `public_html` directory?

Comment: that was my mistake: my Apache default folder was `/var/www/html`, not anything like `public_html` as usual.

Comment: @RomanMatveev Are you saying the issue was resolved by editing/referencing the correct directory?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that you actually want a redirect.  A redirect puts an ugly port number into the URL visible to the client.

It would be more desirable to use a reverse proxy it most cases.   A reverse proxy has your main server connect to your backend API port, get the content and relay it back to the client without the client ever knowing about the backend URL.

To implement that, you would enable the Apache proxy modules from the command line (Debian/Ubuntu command, you may need to look up other commands on other distributions):

```
sudo a2enmod proxy && sudo a2enmod proxy_http && sudo service apache2 restart
```

Then add this code to your Apache configuration files, usually in your `VirtualHost` that handles the site.

```
ProxyRequests Off
ProxyPass /api/ http://localhost:5000/
ProxyPassReverse /api/ http://localhost:5000/
```

Alternately, after enabling the proxy modules, you can change your rewrite rule to do a reverse proxy using the `P` flag rather than `R=301` flag if you first solve the problems of your .htaccess file not taking effect from MrWhite's answer.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^api/(.*[^/])/?$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}:5000/$1 [P,L]
```